# Como usar a condição if no jquery com uso de variaveis?

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando comparar o preço de venda e o valor da taxa em cima do preço de venda. exemplo: o produto custa **1467,73R$**. a minha taxa é de **20%**.Neste caso 20% em cima do preço do produto daria **1761,276R$** 
Quero que quando for digitar o valor da venda(preço do produto), o campo não pode aceitar um valor meno que o preço de venda que deve ser **1761,276R$** por que acrescentamos 20%. 
O erro é que mesmo digitando um valor acima do que foi pedido, o alerta do que foi digitado um valor menos do que o esperando continua aparecendo. Não sei o que deveria fazer.Alguém consegue ajudar?

Agora no Jquery:

```js
$("#qty").click(function() {
  var taxa = $("#taxa").val(); //0,2
  var Price = $("#valor_tabela").val(); // 1467,73
  var PriceHot = $("#valor_venda").val(value).val();
  var totalTaxa = parseInt(taxa) * parseFloat(Price); //293,546
  var percent = parseFloat(totalTaxa) + parseFloat(Price); //293,546 + 1467,73 =1761,276

  if ($("#valor_venda").val() < percent) {

    $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);
    alert('O valor da venda é menor que o valor tabelado!');
  } else {
    $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
    var value = $("#valor_venda").val();
    var primaryincome = $("#qty").val();
    var otherincome = $("#valor_venda").val(value).val();
    // Alterado o sinal de '+', para  '*'
    var totalincome = parseInt(primaryincome) * parseFloat(otherincome);
    $("#result").val(totalincome);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
  <label>Valor Tabelado</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_tabela" id="valor_tabela" value="1467,73" readonly>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taxa" id="taxa" value="0,2" readonly>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label>Valor Venda</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor venda em R$" name="valor_venda" id="valor_venda">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
  <label>Quantidade</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control calculate" id="qty" name="quantidade" value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 mt-2 ">
  <label>Sub Total</labe>
<input type="number" class="form-control"  id="result" name="sub_total"  readonly>
                              </div>
```

---

Comment: Já começa errado que valor monetário não deve ser tratado com `parseFloat()`, algo como 1200,50 com `parseFloat()` vai se tornar 1200.

Comment: deveria ser pasrInt() no caso?

Comment: Não, ele vai transformar seu valor em inteiro, usa `toLocaleString()`



https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: @developer.mozilla.org eu testei trocando tudo em parsInt() e funcionou só que claro vou ter tudo em inteiro.mas ai Troquei todas as variaveis com parseFloat() e deu certo. valeu galera. vocês me deram uma luz para resolver esse problema e eu agradeço :)

Comment: Recomendo que coloque sua resposta na pergunta para ela não ser fechada, tenha em mente que pode ajudar outras pessoas

Comment: @Azzi sim, eu acabei de postar. so que so pode aceitar a resposta em dois dias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o valor da taxa estava vendo como inteiro usando parseInt() então troquei para parsFloat e deu tudo certo.

```js
$("#qty").click(function () {
       var taxa = $("#taxa").val();//0,2
       var Price = $("#valor_tabela").val();// 1467,73
       var totalTaxa = parseFloat(taxa) * parseFloat(Price);//293,546
       var percent = parseFloat(totalTaxa) + parseFloat(Price);//293,546 + 1467,73 =1761,276
  
        if( $("#valor_venda").val() < percent){
              
              $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);
              alert('O valor da venda é menor que o valor tabelado!');
        }
        else{
          $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
          var value = $("#valor_venda").val();
          var primaryincome = $("#qty").val();
          var otherincome = $("#valor_venda").val(value).val();
          // Alterado o sinal de '+', para  '*'
          var totalincome = parseInt(primaryincome) * parseFloat(otherincome);
          $("#result").val(totalincome);
        }
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
  <label>Valor Tabelado</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_tabela" id="valor_tabela" value="1467,73" readonly>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taxa" id="taxa" value="0,2" readonly>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label>Valor Venda</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor venda em R$" name="valor_venda" id="valor_venda">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
  <label>Quantidade</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control calculate" id="qty" name="quantidade" value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 mt-2 ">
  <label>Sub Total</labe>
<input type="number" class="form-control"  id="result" name="sub_total"  readonly>
                              </div>
```